# Is there a counter-example to this problem on convergence of a bounded, strictly increasing sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

I came across this problem in an old set of class notes:

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty, bounded set.  Let $\alpha = \sup{A}$, and let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $A$, with $a = \lim{a_n}$.  Give an example where $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing, yet $a \ne \alpha$.

It seems to me that a counter-example does not exist.  Otherwise, wouldn't this violate Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Comment: $A=[0,1]$. $a_n={1\over2}-{1\over 2n}$.

Comment: Oh, because the set is not necessarily just the image of the sequence... can't believe i missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question stands it can't be solved, but not because of the issues you suspect. If $A$ is finite, then there simply are no strictly increasing sequences in it at all. Even if $A$ is infinite, it does not guarantee the existence of such a sequence as requested. For instance, in the set $A=\{-1/n\mid n\ge 1\}\cup \{0\}$ all strictly increasing sequences converge to the least upper bound, $0$. It would appear that by "give an example ...." it is meant that you are free to choose $A$ as well (the question is poorly worded). Then $A=[-1,1]$ and the sequence $a_n=-1/n$ works.

Comment: Doesn't that example converge to its supremum?  Though you could just make $A = [-1,0] \cup \{1\}$, right?

Comment: thanks @jwalk, I corrected it.